# How to add an available network printer using java code?

Tags: java, swing, batch-file, printing

I would like to get the list of available network printers, and allow users to install (add) a selected printer on their pc using a JButton.

I have searched the net and did find a java api called java printer api but this didn't help me.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: You want to install it or send a print command ?

Comment: Install it (add it to available printers in Control Panel --> Printers... so users can actually use it)

Comment: You have to add printers through windows services only... Java can only allow you to connect to it, print through it and see remaining printing jobs.... and for this what java printer api is....

Comment: So there is no way to automate the install process ? Execute a batch script maybe ?

Comment: Sorry no idea... and my internet connection can end anytime... So i will suggest keep googling around you would surely find..

Comment: Whenever you have to integrated Java code with platform specific and non-standard services like printing, you are going to have to write some clever code if an existing API does not give you what you need. It would not surprise me in the least if a native component is needed in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have probably realized, the standard Java [Print service API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/print/package-summary.html) is for printing documents from a Java application.  It works by interacting with an existing printer or print service provided by the host system.  It does not address the concerns of setting up or configuring printers or print services.

> I would like to get the list of available network printers, and allow users to install (add) a selected printer on their PC using a `JButton`.

The Java printing APIs don't provide that functionality.

> So there is no way to automate the install process? Execute a batch script maybe?

If it is possible to automate printer installation, discovery, configuration (or what have you) using a shell script or batch file that can be run by an unprivileged user, then it is possible (actually simple) to get Java to run the script.

Writing that script is likely the hard part, and it is not a Java programming problem.  And if you can't write / find a script to do this, then your chances of doing printer setup from a Java program are about zero.  While it may be technically possible to do the task in Java, it is (IMO) not worth the development effort to do it that way.

Comment: @StephenC, I want to achieve similar thing, but I think mine is easier, I just want to install a virtual printer in a machine, like PDF printer, could I achieve this easily with java?

Comment: If you can write a shell script / batch file to do it, then yes.   (Write the script, and then get Java to run the script.)   Otherwise no.